# free-jqgrid: can I use multiple comparison-operators for stype: select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using `stype: 'select'` in a basic free-jqgrid.
For one column I want to change the comparison operator for each value in my `select`:

```
stype: 'select',
searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq', 'lt', 'gt'], value: '0:Zero;0:Smaller;0:Bigger;' }
```

so i can search for values that equal zero, are smaller or bigger than zero.

as the jqgrid-documentation states about the `sopt` array:

> When used in toolbar searching the first element is used.

so my example above won't work.

is there any way to solve this problem?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> When used in toolbar searching the first element is used.

is related to the usage of `filterToolbar` *without parameters*. On the other side the usage of `searchOperators: true` options of `filterToolbar` (or inside of `searching` parameter of jqGrid) creates searching operations for input/select fields of the searching bar. The list of possible operations depends on the value of `sopt` property of `searchoptions`. As the result the user can choose the required searching operation. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm), where "Shipped via" column is close to the column which you use.

Comment: oh, thank you once again! seems like I did not find the `searchOperators: true` option for the toolbar anywhere in the documentation(s). but is there also a way to "hardcode" the comparison-operator for the user? so for example in my select i have options for "greater than 0", "smaller than 0" etc. and can use the right comparison-operator accordingly?

Comment: @low_rents: You are welcome! The operations like `'lt'` and `'gt'` seems to me have no sense for `<select>`. The user see the choice between **textes**: `Zero`, `Smaller` and `Bigger`. The corresponding ids from `value` (like `71`, `10`, `42` in case of `71:Zero;10:Smaller;42:Bigger`) will be used in filtering. The exact behavior can depend on other properties of the column. The usage of `71:Zero;10:Smaller;42:Bigger` instead of `Zero:Zero;Smaller:Smaller;Bigger:Bigger` have sense only if you use `formatter: "select"` and the input data in the column as the ids: `71`, `10`, `42`.

Comment: @low_rents: I'm not sure that you use correct `value` in your example. In any way, free jqGrid allows you to implement *any* your custom filtering behavior. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Custom-filtering-searching-Operation).